# BufferedWriter.newLine() except after the last line

Tags: java, bufferedwriter

I'm drawing a blank on this.  The problem I'm facing is I don't want a `newLine()` created after the last line is written to the new file.  How can I accomplish this?

```
while (((aLine = reader.readLine()) != null)) {
                writer.write(aLine);
                writer.newLine();
            }
```

Comment: Switch that and do a `newLine()` before each line except the first. It's harder to tell when you're at the last line but it should be easy to tell which is the first.

Comment: @Thomas: Will that not generate an extra new line before the first line?

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi well, I wrote "...except the first". That shouldn't create a new line before the first line. ;)

Comment: oh ok sorry I didn't realize you mentioned except the first. That way you are right.

Comment: Thanks for your input guys n gals.  tevemadar's answer seems to articulate this perfectly for me :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you can not see the future, you have to rely on the past: instead of emitting a newline after the last line, emit it before all lines, except the first one:

```
bool first=true;
while (((aLine = reader.readLine()) != null)) {
    if(!first)writer.newLine();
    else first=false;
    writer.write(aLine);
}
```

Comment: "As you can not see the future" - I like that :)

Comment: @Thomas I like that too :)  Thanks tevemadar for your eloquence and help.

Answer (score 0):

```
boolean flag = false;
while (((aLine = reader.readLine()) != null)) {
    if(flag)
        writer.newLine();
    writer.write(aLine);
    flag = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As a slight variation on the existing answers (which propose writing the newline first):

```
String separator = "";
while (((aLine = reader.readLine()) != null)) {
  writer.write(separator);
  writer.write(aLine);
  separator = System.lineSeparator();
}
```